# Align radio button left in Mozilla

Tags: css, radio-button, mozilla

I have this situation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    input[type="radio"] {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="radio" name="" id="">

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is radio input stay center horizontally and I need to be align on left. The width must stay 100% and must be supported by IE11+.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible with just the radio input, maybe you can use a label to achieve the effect you're after? Why must the width be 100%?

Comment: I also use a label, but Angular is not update user click, must toggle radio button. I put radio button full with to be over label to catch also user's label click.

Comment: I have feeling is a browser bug, classic for Mozilla...

Comment: It's not a browser bug, I think it's intended. In Chrome it's also aligned left. Can you post your label code as well? It should work if you point the for attribute to the input id.

Comment: <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 radio-toggle">
                                <input id="relationProspectPersonnelPolitiquementExposee-{{$index}}" ng-click="toggleRadio($event)" ng-mouseover="getState($event)" type="radio" name="lien" ng-value="lien.id" />
                                <label for="relationProspectPersonnelPolitiquementExposee-{{$index}}">{{lien.label}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: .radio-toggle {
 position: relative;
}
.radio-toggle input[type="radio"] {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 width: auto;
 padding-right: 100%;
 left: 12px;
}
.radio-toggle label {
 padding-left: 16px;
}
.radio-toggle.style2 label {
 padding-left: 32px;
}

Comment: In chrome it works perfectly.

Comment: You're listening for a click event on the radio input. If you click a label it doesn't trigger a click event on the radio input, it triggers a change event (if the radio button isn't already checked). Try using ng-change instead of ng-click.

Comment: Side-track: if it works in a browser and doesn't work in another, doesn't necessarily mean it's a bug in the latter :-) It could also be a bug in the former (not respecting the specs, misinterpretation, client bug, etc.). If you still think that's a bug in Firefox, please feel free to file a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Yes, that's my feeling, if i set position absolute, left/right 0 and nothing, how it sounds for you?!